# React class component with nested map() to display data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to display the data in the class component which has nested map() methods?

Below is the data structure.

### data.js

```
const items =
{
    "label": "DTR-01",
    "row": [
        {
            "level": 1,
            "locations": [
                {
                    "name": "DTR-01-01",
                    "stock": [
                        {
                            "product": "Battery Drill",
                            "qty": 100,
                            "replenishment": "slow"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "level": 2,
            "locations": [
                {
                    "name": "DTR-01-02",
                    "stock": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "DTR-02-02",
                    "stock": [
                        {
                            "product": "Angle Grinder",
                            "qty": 3,
                            "replenishment": "fast"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "level": 3,
            "locations": [
                {
                    "name": "DTR-01-03",
                    "stock": [
                        {
                            "product": "Skill Saw",
                            "qty": 2,
                            "replenishment": "standard"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "DTR-01-04",
                    "stock": [
                        {
                            "product": "Hammer Drill",
                            "qty": 10,
                            "replenishment": "standard"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

export default items;
```

Have the component set up which is currently returning the Objects, 3 in number.

The class component below.

### LocalData.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import items from '../data/data';

class LocalData extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: items
        };
    }

    render() {
        const {items} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    Object.keys(items.row).map(level => {
                        return (<div key={level}>{level}</div>)
                    })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LocalData;
```

I would need to nest other map() methods to display the data in the component? I have tried nesting the map() methods but end up with errors.

Comment: Remember map only works on arrays. You might need to select the next property which is an array to map over it. Like `rows.map(row => row.locations.map(location =>` etc

Comment: try this `Object.keys(items.row).map((level, index) =>  (<div key={index}>{level}</div>))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified version added here without the need to check isArray.

### Stock.js

```
import React from 'react';
import items from '../data/data';


const Stock = () => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            {items.row.map((value, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                    <div>{value.level}</div>
                    {value.locations.map((val, idx) => (
                        <div key={idx}>
                            <div>{val.name}</div>
                            {val.stock.map((v, i) => (
                                <p key={i}>Product: {v.product} Qty:{v.qty}</p>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    ))}
                    <hr/>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Stock;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my code:

```
    const isArray = arr => !!(arr && Array.isArray(arr));

    const MyComponent = ({ collection }) =>
      Array.isArray(collection) ? (
        <div>
          {collection.map((item, index) =>
            item && isArray(item.locations) ? (
              <div key={index}>
                {item.level}
                {item.locations.map((item, index) => (
                  <div key={index}>
                    {item.name}
                    {isArray(item.stock) && (
                        <div>
                        {item.stock.map((stock, index) => (
                          <div key={index}>
                            {stock.product}
                            <MyComponent collection={item.locations} />
                          </div>
                        ))}
                        </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div key={index}> {item && (item.level || item.name)} </div>
            )
          )}
        </div>
      ) : null;

    render() {
        const { items } = this.state;
        return (
          <div>
            {
              <MyComponent collection={items.row} />
            }
          </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Trying out your code, the line with `{item.stock.map((stock, index) => (` is throwing an error, **Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
**. Have you tried this in a class component? Thanks

Comment: I wrapped the code in the above comment in a div all working perfectly thanks for the code snippet. My IDE highlighted the isArray and simplified it as: `const isArray = arr => !!(arr && Array.isArray(arr));
` Thanks again.